# How can I solve the below error in Angular v6 -> v11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular9, angular11

How can I resolve the following error in Angular after upgrading from v6 to v11?

> An unhandled exception occurred: Failed to compile entry-point
> ngx-editor (es2015 as esm2015) due to compilation
> errors:node_modules/ngx-editor/fesm2015/ngx-editor.js:1147:26 - error
> NG1010: Value at position 3 in the NgModule.imports of NgxEditorModule
> is not a reference   Value could not be determined statically.
>
> 1147                 imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule,
> ReactiveFormsModule, PopoverModule.forRoot()],
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/ngx-editor/fesm2015/ngx-editor.js:1147:75
> 1147                 imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, PopoverModule.forRoot()],
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Unable to evaluate this expression statically.   node_modules/ngx-editor/fesm2015/ngx-editor.js:1147:75
> 1147                 imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, PopoverModule.forRoot()],
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Unknown reference.
>
> See "C:\Users\cis\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-S48jMx\angular-errors.log" for
> further details.

Comment: You should update the `ngx-editor` also to the latest version

Comment: import { NgxEditorModule } from 'ngx-editor'; and add the entryin in imports section.

Comment: import { NgxEditorModule } from 'ngx-editor'; ,also update it to latest version using npm install ngx-editor --save but problem is not resolve.

Comment: @AnkitGairola after an update from v6 to v11, i would strongly advice you to just remove your `node_modules` folder, and run `npm i` again. This will start up the `ngcc` process as well

Comment: @PoulKruijt, I also did the same as above by deleting node_modules and ran npm i.. still, it is not resolved

Comment: @AnkitGairola it looks like you did not update ngx-editor to the latest version. Run `npm i ngx-editor@latest`

Comment: @PoulKruijt Thanks brother for helping me. The errors are resolved now.

Comment: Hi will it be possible for you to share your code snippet over [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). Mainly your package.json file. So that it would give us some better insights